# Preventing user input when running Minitest

Tags: ruby, minitest

When running my Minitest file, my entire Ruby program get run and prompts the user for input. Any values entered here won't be used in the tests.

Is there a way of hiding/ignoring all user prompts when running the test file? Is it also possible to only run the individual methods that are being tested, rather than the whole program?

Command used to run the Minitest file:
**ruby -Itest test_calc.rb**

test_calc.rb:

```
require './calc'
require 'minitest/autorun'

class TestMarkupCalc < Minitest::Test

  def test_amount_input_for_float
    assert_kind_of(Float, amount_input("price"))
  end

  def test_amount_input_for_integer
    assert_kind_of(Integer, amount_input("number"))
  end

  def test_flat_markup
    assert_equal(1050, flat_markup(1000))
  end

  def test_num_workers_markup
    assert_equal(0.06, num_workers(5))
  end
end
```

Comment: What does the `calc.rb` do which you include at the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you've said and the test you posted, I am guessing that your program doesn't define a `MarkupCalc` class and that methods like `amount_input`, `flat_markup`, and `num_workers` are top-level methods.  To do what you're asking, you'll need to create a class like:

```
class MarkupCalc
  def self.amount_input(name)
    # ...
  end

  def self.flat_markup(amount)
    # ...
  end

  def self.num_workers(num)
    # ...
  end
end
```

And then rewrite your test to call the methods accordingly:

```
class TestMarkupCalc < Minitest::Test
  def test_amount_input_for_float
    assert_kind_of(Float, MarkupCalc.amount_input("price")
  end

  # ...
end
```